# Seeking a German Siddur

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, prayer-book, ashkenazi, nusach-ashkenaz

I was wondering if there is a 'Minhag Ashkenaz' siddur presently in print. I have an older one at home, but it has sentimental value and as a university student, I would rather avoid using such a siddur on campus. I typically use a Siddur Rinat Yisrael, but tachanun and birchot hashachar are different from the German variant.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, that's a somewhat older version of R' Rallis's siddur from his answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been compiling a German siddur for the past fifteen years. It is currently available on www.thebookpatch.com:

http://www.thebookpatch.com/BookStoreDetails.aspx?BookID=19123&ID=0da30d3e-df41-4b72-bdbe-ee301d7f0000

Comment: Thanks for the link and welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site, including its 82 other _[tag:sidur]_ questions.

Comment: @Rallis, do you have a sample text that I could view, also, I have access to a digital printing press, if you want I could send you the info.

Comment: Here is a link to my siddur which is currently available on www.thebookpatch.com http://www.thebookpatch.com/BookStoreDetails.aspx?BookID=19123&ID=0da30d3e-df41-4b72-bdbe-ee301d7f0000

Comment: @RallisWiesenthal, is this identical to Siddur Sefas Yisroel on Open Siddur?

Answer (score 5):

This [2011 link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4aJ5_n3eJDpOWExYjk3NjUtZTBiMi00OTgwLWJlZjctOWIwYWY4Njg1ZWNj/edit?hl=en%3ahuejyki3#)
to the Siddur Tefillas Yeshurun metioned by yitznewton may be valuable to sign up for the new edition. You can also contact www.kayj.net

You ask for printed editions. The following are available online. You could print what you wanted I suppose.

1. A Category at the Wikimedia Commons for scanned works of Wolf Heidenheim, including a full set of mahzorim and many editions of his siddur:
   http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Wolf_Heidenheim
2. A Category at the Wikimedia Commons for scanned works of Seligman Baer, including two scans of Avodat Yisrael and one of Kinnot:
   http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Seligman_Baer

Answer (score 3):

*Siddur Sfat Emet* (known as the Rödelheim siddur) is in-print and available for sale here:
http://www.booksnbagels.com/eng/productinfo.php?id=9708

Comment: This siddur is not the correct Minhag Ashkenaz. There are many mistakes in the Sfas Emes Siddur. Also, the Birkas HaMinim is the post-censored version. Hashiva Shofteinu has an extra word and there are several spelling mistakes throughout the siddur.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.moreshesashkenaz.org/en/associated-publications/76-tefilas-yeshurun-2

I have a copy of the OOP 1st ed, second is in prep

Comment: Fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for a German Siddur, the siddur of Rav. Hirsch is probably the best option. It is in the style of Minhag Frankfurt, which is more of the Ashkenaz minhag than Siddurs from Northern Germany.

[https://www.amazon.com/Hirsch-Siddur-Order-Prayers-Whole/dp/087306142X/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=The+Hirsch+Siddur&qid=1570317161&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/087306142X)