# Standard Orthodox Siddur in France

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, chutz-laaretz, nusach-ashkenaz

I was in France over the summer. On Shabbat, I decided to go to the nearest schul, Ohel Avraham, a 5-minute walk from where I was staying. I realised there that the siddur they were using was very similar to the old Rödelheim Siddur, which is my first choice.

Does anyone know what this siddur is called?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33479/seeking-a-german-siddur

Answer (score 1):

(I'm french) the siddur used by west european ashkenazi communities here in France is called Sha'arei Tefila. It is similar to the Rodelheim one with french annotations and few asaltian customs.
It has been made by an alsatian rav called Rav Yoseph Bloch in 1924 and is still in use and regularly republished (last by Biblieurope ed. in 2013).
The other french ashkenazi communities use mainly siddur kol peh.