# Shortened אמת ויציב

Tags: tefilla, provenance, bircas-krias-shema

In Nusach Ashkenaz, particularly in western siddurim (Heidenheim, Bloch, et c.) There is a shortened version of the paragraphs of אמת ויציב and על הראשונים which is recited when a zulat (yotzer before עזרת) is recited (in Eastern Ashkenazi siddurim, only the portion from על הראשונים is recited). It is shown below:

> אֱמֶת וְיַצִּיב וְנָכוֹן וְקַיָּם וְיָשָׁר וְנֶאֱמָן וְטוֹב וְיָפֶה הַדָּּבָר הַזֶה עַל אֲבוֹתֵֽינוּ וְעָלֵֽנוּ עַל בָנֵֽנוּ וְעַל דּוֹרוֹתֵֽנוּ וְעַל כָּל–דּוֹרוֹת זֶרַֽע יִשְׂרָאֵל עֲבָדֶֽךָ:‏
>
> עַל הָרִאשׁוֹנִים וְעַל הָאַחֲרוֹנִים לְעוֹלָם וָעֶד חֹק וְלֹא יַעֲבוֹר.
> אֱמֶת  שָׁאַתָּה הוּא ה׳ אֱלֹהֵֽנוּ וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתֵֽינוּ לְעוֹלָם
> וָעֶד: אַתָּה הוּא מַלכֵֽנוּ מֶֽלֶךְ  אַבוֹתֵֽנוּ אָֽתָּה. לְמַֽעַן
> שִׁמְךָ מַהֵר לְגָאֳלֵֽנוּ כַּאֲשֶׁר גָאַֽלְתָּ (*נ"א* כְּגָאַלְתָּ)
> אֶת אֲבוֹתֵֽינוּ: אֱמֱת מֵעוֹלָם שִׁמְךָ הַגָּדוֹל עָלֵֽינוּ נִקְרָא
> בְּאַהֲבָה. אֵין אֱלֹהִים (* עוֹד) זוּלָתֶֽךָ: ‏

This text appears in full in in various machzorim, at least as early as the [mid-18th century](https://books.google.com/books?id=yZI9AAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA20#v=onepage&q=%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%AA&f=false), as well as the Alexander Siddur (London, 5569), [most Rödelheim editions](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Wolf_Heidenheim), and the [Bloch Siddur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53479/4504). The text for על הראשונים also appears in the Routledge/Adler Machzorim for Shalosh Regalim.

What is the provenance of this variant as it appears above?

Comment: @Fred et al., seems like tehre's material here worth posting as an answer.