# Western Ashkenazi Siddur?

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, nusach-ashkenaz, yekke

Does anyone know where I can find an authoritative Yekkish siddur? I found a siddur Sefas Yisroel on open siddur, but I am unsure it's accurate — meaning one that accurately reflects the nusach of the Western Ashkenazi Mesorah as was practiced in Frankfurt and other German cities. I would also like a physical siddur.

Any tips?

Comment: I think you should contact [K'hal Adath Jeshurun](http://www.kajinc.org/contact-us) in Washington Heights and ask them what siddur they use, since they are the the primary practicioners today of the minhag of Frankfort-am-Main.

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33479/seeking-a-german-siddur.    Also see https://www.kayj.net/en/forum/minhogim/2230-hirsch-siddur#2600 which says that the siddur Sfas Yisroel has some issues with accuracy.

Comment: See [here](http://www.booksnbagels.com/eng/productinfo.php?id=9708&curcat=d60&main_cat=a1), [here](http://www.booksnbagels.com/eng/productinfo.php?id=prd7941&curcat=&main_cat=), and [here](http://www.booksnbagels.com/eng/searchresults.php?Sstr=machsor+schma+kolenu&filter=none). [This site](http://www.booksnbagels.com/) might just have everything you're looking for. But then again, my German is quite awful and I don't know much about Jeckische minhogim.

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62437/759

Comment: @Ask613, you're misconstruing what I noted in that KAYJ forum thread. The Hirsch siddur has some problems. I just don't like the typography of Tefiloh Sefas Yisroel

Answer (score 7):

The Siddur used by most German communities nowadays is the Sfas Emes Siddur published by Victor Goldschmidt Publishing. However, even at its first publication in 1799, the nusach had been changed to reflect some of the customs that were being practiced in Eastern Europe (Poland). You can get a copy of the Sfas Emes for yourself from Ephraim Rosenstock in Washington Heights.

Rabbi Hamburger in B'nei Brak had published a more authoritative one, but it's out of print. Rabbi Hoffmeister of Vienna also [published one](https://www.moreshesashkenaz.org/en/associated-publications/76-tefilas-yeshurun-2) (I have a copy and it's great), but I don't know if it's still available.

[This one](http://olastamid.com/) is nice too, but it's currently only a work in progress. (Note I am working on it.)

Comment: http://www.booksnbagels.com/eng/productinfo.php?id=9708&curcat=d60&main_cat=a1 It's Hebrew with German instructions, the description says (for those who cannot read German).