# Yekke Tallit Gadol

Tags: tallit-gadol, yekke

I am a Yekke and am unsure about some of the customs such as a good Siddur to use (My Rabbi is Chassidish so I use Nusach Sfard) and also a Tallit Gadol.  I'd prefer to use the Tallit that is all white.  Is there a mesorah in this?

Comment: Conversations have lead me to understand that the minhag is to wear white stripes only on high holidays, though this minhag may have fallen out of practice. FWIW I always wear black stripes. In regards to the siddur: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71298/western-ashkenazi-siddur?rq=1

Comment: One should be careful about changing one's minhagim. If you do not have a strong mesorah concerning your status as a Jecke, it might be best to follow the minhagim of your rabbi or community. On a side note, Nusach Sfard is not relevant to Jeckes, as it contains many kabbalistic additions and piyutim according to the Arizal. Since a majority of Jeckishe rabbonim rejected the Zohar in general, a Jecke shouldn't daven Sfard unless he rejects his other Jeckishe minhagim. As with any case, it's always best to CYLOR.

Comment: Yisroel, you may be interested in [our other questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=yekke) concerning Jeckes and their minhagim.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a Jekke, so I think I can answer this from communal experience. [Most](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gP4fMiXiS5Y/maxresdefault.jpg) [Jekkes](http://godaven.com/detail.asp?Id=5900) now use [black-striped](https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.shulcloud.com/288/uploads/Chazzonim%20Frankel%20and%20Abe%20Wertheim.png) [tallisaus](https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.shulcloud.com/288/uploads/Rav%20Breuer%20Address.png) during the year ([only married men wear white stripes, and only then during Yomim Noroim](http://www.kayj.net/en/forum/minhogim/193-white-kaepchen-sargenes-tallis-for-rqh-and-yqk?limitstart=0)). Historically, light blue stripes were common, as can be seen in Moritz Oppenheim's paintings, although this is no longer the case, as above. I personally wear a Belzer-style tallis with midnight blue stripes, altho

The best siddur for Jekkes to use these days is R' Rallis Wiesenthal's *[Tefiloh Sefas Yisroel](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qoj5lwevr8y9n0d/Tefiloh-Sefas-Yisroel-v.1.16.pdf?dl=0)*, which is edited following Rishonic and early Acharonic German siddurim. Nusach Sfard is not appropriate, as it doesn't adhere to our Rishonim.

A final note, our poskim are incredibly strict in opposing the usage of "oy" for the חוֹלם vowel. There's an article in the siddur I linked which discusses this.

Comment: I heard that green stripes were also once used on the tallisos gedolos in Jeckishe kehillos back in the day. Is that true?

Comment: @ezra, it's possible, although I've never seen a green-striped tallis from before the late 20th century.

Comment: Some Jekkes pronounce the חולם as an "ow".

Comment: @wolf_math, I do so as well. It doesn't have the same problems as "oy"

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I didn't mean to imply that it was problematic ;)

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt The article in the back of the siddur (You have to scroll past the first 414 or so pages to get there.) you link to is great. Everyone should make the effort to check it out. It's very informative.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Why is there a problem with pronouncing the vowel as [oj]? Why would [au] be any preferable?

Comment: @ezra, [oj] adds a י, which would affect בגד כפת, whereas the וּ in [au] wouldn't specifically do so. Did you read the article at the back of the siddur?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - I still need to read the article, but now I see what you're saying. However, wouldn't [au] be a problem of אַוּ? Besides, I think it's pretty much confirmed that the vowel should be pronounced [o]. (By the way, I pronounce it [oj], quite sheepishly.)

Comment: @ezra, look at Arabic and Teimani Hebrew. Arabic has a similar אַוּ phoneme as Jekkisch Hebrew, rather than [o]. The question of whether חוֹלם should be a diphthong is an old question in any case, and it's somewhat more difficult to answer.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Something I will have to look into. :) Thanks for the lesson. I actually am under the opinion that the [au] in Jekkisch Hebrew comes from the sound in the German language, in the similar way that the [s] for thaw was corrupted because [th] in Old German is pronounced [s].

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Au is not, however, preferable to ow - אָו, as explained by Rav Hamburger Shlit''a in Shorshei Minhog Ashkenaz Volume 1, and can clearly be seen in the Radak and Mishnas HaGro

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I should point out that a much more accurate Yekkish Siddur is the תפלת ישרון